# How to get RSSI when I'm connecting to Net with GPRS?

Tags: android, gprs, rssi

I want to write an Android application that can show current connectivy's RSSI.
In WIFI connectivy, i can get RSSI with WifiInfo.getRssi().
My question is how can i get RSSI in GPRS connectivy?
May be I can use GSM's RSSI for the GPRS connectivy's RSSI?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GPRS is an add-on to the GSM network, so you can use the GSM RSSI value.